# Invalid Request Errors - What are these console errors?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

While deploying an app to App Engine Flexible, I am getting these errors.

> #### Client Error
>
> The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
>
> This is try #1
>   Oct 15, 2018 2:47:26 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
>   WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%5Bcarpal-shorturl%5D&version=1&
>   400 Bad Request
>
> #### Client Error
>
> The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
>
> This is try #2
>   Oct 15, 2018 2:47:27 PM com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection send1
>   WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%5Bcarpal-shorturl%5D&version=1&
>   400 Bad Request
>
> #### Client Error
>
> The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
>
> This is try #3
>   com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%5Bcarpal-shorturl%5D&version=1&
>   400 Bad Request
>
> #### Client Error
>
> The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
>
> Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=%5Bcarpal-shorturl%5D&version=1&
>   400 Bad Request
>
> #### Client Error
>
> The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: It seems you have square brackets [ ] around your project Id. Remove them and try again to deploy.

Comment: thank you.. it worked yesterday. I removed square brackets and it deployed successfully.

Comment: @LundinCast Would you mind posting your solution as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Answer (score 0):

As LundinCast said, removing the square brackets [ ] around the project ID will fix the issue.